# Python / Pyside Code not executing sequentially?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I am building a Qt-based GUI using Pyside. Inside a specific class who has access to a QMainWindow (`_theMainWindow`) class which in turn has access to 2 other Qt Widgets (`theScan` & `theScanProgress`) I am trying to `show()` the last one by executing

```
def initiateScan(self):
    self._theMainWindow.theScan.theScanProgress.show()
```

This works just fine, the theScanProgress widget appears.

However, when I add the line that makes the application sleep (and a print statement), as below

```
def initiateScan(self):
    self._theMainWindow.theScan.theScanProgress.show()
    print("test")
    time.sleep(3)
```

the program seems to go to sleep BEFORE the widget appears, i.e. as if the `time.sleep(3)` gets executed before `self._theMainWindow.theScan.theScanProgress.show()`

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: can you tell us what type `theScanProgress` is?

Comment: it's a QDialog object (created using QtDesigner and compiled to a .py file using pyside-uic tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the main loop which processes gui events.  If you are not using threads you can only execute one function at a time.  I strongly suspect that `show` emits a signal which goes into the event queue, which is in turn blocked until the current function returns.

Put another way, Qt is event driven, and it can only do one event at a time.  What ever you did call `initiateScan` added an event to the stack that was to execute the function (something like you pushed a button, which emitted a signal, which then triggered the function), and that function can do some computation, alter internal state of your objects, and add events to the stack.  What `show` does underneath is emit a signal to all of it's children for them to show them selves.  For that code to run, it has to wait for the current event (the function with your sleep) to return.  During the `sleep` the entire gui will be unresponsive for the exact same reason.

[I probably butchered some of the terms of art]

Comment: So, in practice, the sequence of events is something like this?: initiateScan is called, then show() emits the signal which is put in a queue, sleep(3) puts the process to sleep and ONLY THEN show() is actually processed? (or should we say: de-queued from the event queue). Let me also say that through the debugger, the show() somehow takes the program to the main .py file that initiates the GUI application and more specifically to the app.exec_() call. After some investigation, this seems to be the rule for every GUI-related method call: all of them transfer the program to app.exec_()

Answer (score 0):

`show` only schedules the appearance of the progress widget. But since you are blocking the main thread with your `sleep`, the main thread cannot perform the scheduled action until you release it.

You have to use threads or find another way to wait 3 seconds.